# Javascript not loading only when logged out from Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'm inserting this script into my wordpress site using Elementor:

`<script src="https://www.fourvenues.com/assets/iframe/"></script>`

It looks great while I'm logged-in but as soon as I log-out I got this error on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at createIframe (events:45:11)
    at script.onload (events:36:7)
```

I thought it might be some DOM content not loaded but used a DOMContentLoaded script but no results.

You can see it in action [here](https://millennialwave.es/fv/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looking at the error, the code is trying to create an iFrame in an element that doesn't exist. Where is `elementId` coming from?

Comment: It's declared in the script: const elementId = 'fourvenues-iframe';

Comment: Where is your JS loading? My guess is this is a [load order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) issue. If that element doesn't exist before the script is loaded, the script will return the error your seeing. Try loading that script in the footer of your site.

Comment: Not working :( what puzzles me is that it works great while I'm logged in. JS loads in place (where I want the iframe to be)

Comment: Do you have a cache mechanism in place like WP Rocket?

Comment: I do. LiteSpeed Cache, I just deactivated it and did the trick.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.